# Syntax highlighting is broken when you don't specify a language explicitly

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

I've noticed that syntax highlighting doesn't work or only sort of works when you don't specify a language tag like

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
```

Shouldn't it be able to autodetect common or known languages?

Here's a question I noticed it on since it has HTML, JS, and CSS blocks that are all not being colored correctly or only partially:

**Screenshot:**

[image: Separate HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code blocks are highlighted as if they're all JavaScript.]

**Link:** [I was trying to make side navigation bar open with a checkbox but when I check the box the side bar doesn't appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65821620/i-was-trying-to-make-side-navigation-bar-with-checkbox-but-when-i-check-the-box)

Comment: Looks like the JS is correctly highlighted to me (and it is the most popular tag on the question), HTML and CSS both look like they're being highlight as JS again because it's the most popular tag on the question. All working as intended. If you want multiple different languages in a post you need to specify them all where they are used

Comment: For the js, the script tags are not highlighted

Comment: Script tags _aren't_ JS, they're HTML that wraps the JS. Of course they're not highlighted.

Comment: If my IDE didn't highlight script tags wrapping the js, I'd think something was wrong, just like I would here

Comment: @chiliNUT If your IDE highlighted script tags in a `.js` file, I'd think there was something wrong with your IDE.(Note that I didn't say `.jsx`.)

Comment: Both the HTML and CSS seem incomplete (not balanced). That changed in [revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/65821620/3).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works for me, as long you don't use `<!-- language: hint -->` as those are deprecated.

From [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work)

> Note that [overriding the default highlighting] is only supported when using the code fence (```) method of code formatting; as of the implementation of CommonMark, doing so on code blocks using the four-space indent method is no longer supported*:

Instead use code fences (three backticks) and place the highlight hint on the starting code fence: ```` ```javascript ```` (if you want the hint used on that tag) or ```` ```lang-javascript ```` (if you want the explicit supported highlighter)

#### Example

Adapted from [source revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/ac63c4c7-ed3a-4e04-8387-2b4afdff7b60/view-source)

---

HTML

```html
<div class="opened-side-nav" id="barres">Content</div>

<div class="logo">
    <input  id="5055" class="showsidenavbar" type="checkbox" onclick="showsidenav()">
    <label for="5055">=</label>
```

JavaScript

```javascript
    <script>
        function showsidenav(){
            document.getElementsById("barres").style.display = "block"; 
        }                                         
              
    </script>
```

CSS

```css
    .opened-side-nav {
    background-color: ghostwhite;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    border-right: black 2px solid;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
```

Answer (score 2):

As [@rene](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene) said, make sure to use code fence syntax when specifying language per code block.

Also wanted to mention that the HTML highlighter is nicely versatile, and will highlight properly formatted JavaScript and CSS in HTML code blocks, as long as you specify the whole block as HTML:

```` ```lang-html ````

```html
<div class="opened-side-nav" id="barres">Content</div>

<div class="logo">
    <input  id="5055" class="showsidenavbar" type="checkbox" onclick="showsidenav()">
    <label for="5055">=</label> 
</div>

<script>
    function showsidenav(){
        document.getElementsById("barres").style.display = "block"; 
    }                                         
</script>

<style>
.opened-side-nav {
    background-color: ghostwhite;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    border-right: black 2px solid;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
}
</style>
```